# extract feature names from trained model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a pre-trained XGBoost model read from a pickle file. When I was trying to make predictions on a new dataset with some columns outside of the feature set of the model, I received the error message:

> training data did not have the following fields: column1, column2,...

I am okay with excluding these columns not existing in training data. Instead of hard-coding the column names (there are many), I would like to just find the intersection between columns of the training and the prediction datasets.

Is there a way I can extract the feature names from the trained model (apparently the model recorded the field names) without having to go back to my training dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its mandatory that prediction dataset should contain only those columns which are present in training dataset. It even makes sense not to include extra columns because the weights are learnt based on your training dataset. Including any extra column apart from training dataset doesn't provide any value or improve your accuracy, because when you are predicting all you do is multiply the learnt weights of model with new values. Make sure not to inlcude any extra feature for predicting.

Comment: I am not trying to include the extra columns. My question was how to get the column names from the model so I can only include the features in the training set.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve feature names from a pickled model as follows:

```
fitted_model.get_booster().feature_names
```